# GitKraken: "This repository requires LFS but you do not have LFS installed"

Tags: git, gitkraken

For a repository on GitHub, GitKraken shows:

> This repository requires LFS but you do not have LFS installed.
>   Modifying files that are tracked by LFS could potentially harm your
>   repository. Please visit our support site for info on installing LFS.

Button: [Support Site](https://support.gitkraken.com/)

However, their support site does not mention "Large File Storage". And the largest file is about 4 MB. How can modifying "large" files harm the repository - potentially corrupted binary data?

And what steps are necessary to meet the requirements here?

[image: lfs]

Comment: Are you sure? https://support.gitkraken.com/?search=lfs+

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> However, their support site does not mention "Large File Storage".

It does, on the [Git LFS Requirements](https://support.gitkraken.com/git-workflows-and-extensions/Intro-and-requirements) page.

> How can modifying "large" files harm the repository...?

Git stores each copy of each file in the repository.  If you have a 4 MB file, that's no big deal.  If you have 1000 revisions of a 4 MB file, that's 4000 MB that is stored locally and transferred every time you clone.

[Git LFS](https://git-lfs.github.com/) works by adding a second object storage area for large files, they will only be transferred when you need to check them out.  In the actual Git repository, a small "pointer file" with the information on where to retrieve the binaries is stored.  So your repository stays small, but you can get the large binaries on demand.

If you try to work with this repository without installing LFS you will (first) not be able to see the actual binary contents, just the pointer file.  You will (second) check binaries into the actual repository, instead of the LFS space, every time you try to add content.  It will not be "corrupt", but it will certainly not be what the originators of the repository intended.

This should be as simple as [following GitKraken's instructions](https://support.gitkraken.com/git-workflows-and-extensions/git-lfs/) to install [Git LFS](https://git-lfs.github.com/).

Comment: Very nicely explained! Sorry for the question, but at `where git-lfs` = `C:\Program Files\Git LFS\git-lfs.exe`, I'm a little stuck. Apparently Git is not "linked" with Git LFS. What is the correct step to "link" the applications?

Comment: Git will look in your `PATH` for helper applications.  If you put `C:\Program Files\Git LFS` in your `PATH` then you should be able to run `git lfs`.

Comment: After adding this and `AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\app-1.0.11\resources\app\git\cmd` to PATH, GitKraken is not showing the message anymore. I suppose it should work now and I hope the repo is still fine. Thanks for the detailed heads-up :) +1

Answer (score 2):

In continuously get the error you reported after every restart of my macOS machine. I need to fix it every time by running

`$ sudo launchctl config user path "/usr/local/bin:$PATH"`

My resolution is taken from their [documentation](https://help.gitkraken.com/gitkraken-client/git-lfs/#using-lfs-installed-using-homebrew-on-macos). The reason seems to be that if Git LFS is installed via homebrew, the path has to be adapted separately for GUI apps.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same problem on macOS. I initially also had lfs installed through homebrew.
I solved it by first removing git-lfs with homebrew:

```
brew uninstall git-lfs
```

Next I installed it again using the steps provided [here](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/working-with-files/managing-large-files/installing-git-large-file-storage) on the website of github.
I rebooted GitKraken and the LFS tab became visible.