# How to download a model from huggingface?

Tags: huggingface-transformers, transformer-model

For example, I want to download `bert-base-uncased` on https://huggingface.co/models, but can't find a 'Download' link. Or is it not downloadable?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The models are automatically cached locally when you first use it.
So, to download a model, all you have to do is run the code that is provided in the [model card](https://huggingface.co/bert-base-uncased) (I chose the corresponding model card for `bert-base-uncased`).

At the top right of the page you can find a button called "Use in Transformers", which even gives you the sample code, showing you how to use it in Python. Again, for `bert-base-uncased`, this gives you the following code snippet:

```py
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForMaskedLM
  
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")
model = AutoModelForMaskedLM.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")
```

When you run this code for the first time, you will see a download bar appear on screen. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61798573/where-does-hugging-faces-transformers-save-models) (disclaimer: I gave one of the answers) if you want to find the actual folder where Huggingface stores their models.

Comment: How to download the models to local disk?

Comment: What if I want to download the model to a specific directory?

Comment: I think that merits its own question; in fact, I believe a possible answer is given here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63312859/how-to-change-huggingface-transformers-default-cache-directory

Comment: While this is simple for Python users (and should allow control over location by setting the `TRANSFORMERS_CACHE` env var or calling `.save_pretrained(folder)` on the resulting objects), it actually loads the model which therefore must fit into CUDA/RAM/etc: Not ideal if you're just fetching the model to cache it somewhere on disk.

Answer (score 67):

`git clone` works fine with getting models from huggingface. Here is an example:

```
git clone https://huggingface.co/sberbank-ai/ruT5-base
```

Note that you need to have `git lfs` installed if you want to actually download the large files in the repo, rather than just references to them. If you run `git lfs --version` and get a "Command not recognized" message, then you haven't got it installed. You can get the latest version from the [official git-lfs website](https://git-lfs.com/), or install an older version using a package manager - for example, on Ubuntu:

```
apt-get install git-lfs
git lfs install
```

Related: [How do I clone a repository that includes Git LFS files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56283415/how-do-i-clone-a-repository-that-includes-git-lfs-files/56284009)

Comment: Just use `git clone <url>`. git has started to throw warning of deprecation. `WARNING: 'git lfs clone' is deprecated and will not be updated
          with new flags from 'git clone' \n
'git clone' has been updated in upstream Git to have comparable
speeds to 'git lfs clone'.`

Comment: Just for everyone like me with the same problem, check here (https://git-lfs.com/) and download the archive (e.g.: "https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/releases/download/v3.3.0/git-lfs-linux-amd64-v3.3.0.tar.gz"). Inside its `install.sh` file set `prefix="${HOME}/.local"` as path where the `install.sh` will find the bin folder to put the `git-lfs` binary. Save it and run the script with `sh ./install.sh` as current user. Once this is done you can use the command `git-lfs clone https://huggingface.co/sberbank-ai/ruT5-base` to clone the repository on huggingface.co

Comment: You have to create a Hugginface account, create a token with a name. When using git clone, use token name as username and token value as password.

Comment: The clone however will copy the whole history, 30GB worth of models could have extra 70GB inside a `.git` folder, so if you do not want to go back in commit history and is not interested in git itself, then you can delete the whole folder to free up some HDD space.

Answer (score 9):

How about using `hf_hub_download` from `huggingface_hub` library?

`hf_hub_download` returns the local path where the model was downloaded so you could hook this one liner with another shell command.

```
python3 -c 'from huggingface_hub import hf_hub_download; downloaded_model_path = hf_hub_download(
                                                          repo_id="CompVis/stable-diffusion-v-1-4-original",
                                                          filename="sd-v1-4.ckpt",
                                                          use_auth_token=True
                                                         ); print(downloaded_model_path)'
```

Answer (score 8):

To download models from Hugging Face, you can use the official CLI tool `huggingface-cli` or the Python method `snapshot_download` from the `huggingface_hub` library.

#### Using `huggingface-cli`:

To download the "bert-base-uncased" model, simply run:

```bash
$ huggingface-cli download bert-base-uncased
```

#### Using `snapshot_download` in Python:

```py
from huggingface_hub import snapshot_download

snapshot_download(repo_id="bert-base-uncased")
```

These tools make model downloads from the Hugging Face Model Hub quick and easy.

For more information and advanced usage, you can refer to the official Hugging Face documentation:

- [`huggingface-cli` Documentation](https://huggingface.co/docs/huggingface_hub/guides/download#download-from-the-cli)
- [`snapshot_download` Documentation](https://huggingface.co/docs/huggingface_hub/v0.17.3/en/package_reference/file_download#huggingface_hub.snapshot_download)

Comment: I get `TypeError: hf_hub_download() got an unexpected keyword argument 'endpoint'` when using the `snapshot_download`

Comment: Python>=3.8 & huggingface_hub>=0.17.0

Answer (score 5):

Hover over the boxy `lfs` icon to get the download link.

```
curl -L https://huggingface.co/TheBloke/falcon-7b-instruct-GGML/resolve/main/falcon-7b-instruct.ggccv1.q4_1.bin --output falcon-7b-instruct.ggccv1.q4_1.bin
```

Answer (score 3):

I typically see if the model has a GitHub repo where I can download the zip file. Due to my company protocols I often cannot directly connect to some sources without getting an SSL certificate error, but I can download from GitHub.

Answer (score 2):

I made this simple tool to help with this

[HuggingFaceModelDownloader](https://github.com/bodaay/HuggingFaceModelDownloader)

you can use it in one line:

```
hfdownloader -m bert-base-uncased
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Curl to download a file from a URL:

```bash
curl -L -O https://huggingface.co/your-file
```

Comment: or wget. both seem to work. (I grabbed the link from the download button)

Answer (score 0):

It's downloadable that goes to `~/.cache/torch/sentence_transformers/bert-base-uncased` by default. For example, if defining in LangChain

```py
embeddings = HuggingFaceEmbeddings(
    model_name="bert-base-multilingual-cased")
```