# Why does llama-index still require an OpenAI key when using Hugging Face local embedding model?

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, huggingface, large-language-model, llama-index

I am creating a very simple question and answer app based on documents using llama-index. Previously, I had it working with OpenAI. Now I want to try using no external APIs so I'm trying the Hugging Face example [in this link](https://gpt-index.readthedocs.io/en/latest/core_modules/model_modules/llms/usage_custom.html#example-using-a-huggingface-llm).

It says in the example in the link: "Note that for a completely private experience, also setup a local embedding model (example here)." I'm assuming the example given below is the example being referred to. So, naturally, I'm trying to copy the example ([fuller example here](https://gpt-index.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/customization/llms/SimpleIndexDemo-Huggingface_stablelm.html)).

Here is my code:

```py
from pathlib import Path
import gradio as gr
import sys
import logging
import os

from llama_index.llms import HuggingFaceLLM
from llama_index.prompts.prompts import SimpleInputPrompt

logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.getLogger().addHandler(logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout))


from llama_index import SimpleDirectoryReader, VectorStoreIndex, ServiceContext, load_index_from_storage, StorageContext

storage_path = "storage/"

docs_path="docs"

def construct_index(directory_path):
    max_input_size = 4096
    num_outputs = 512
    #max_chunk_overlap = 20
    chunk_overlap_ratio = 0.1
    chunk_size_limit = 600

    #prompt_helper = PromptHelper(max_input_size, num_outputs, chunk_overlap_ratio, chunk_size_limit=chunk_size_limit)

    system_prompt = """<|SYSTEM|># StableLM Tuned (Alpha version)
    - StableLM is a helpful and harmless open-source AI language model developed by StabilityAI.
    - StableLM is excited to be able to help the user, but will refuse to do anything that could be considered harmful to the user.
    - StableLM is more than just an information source, StableLM is also able to write poetry, short stories, and make jokes.
    - StableLM will refuse to participate in anything that could harm a human.
    """

    # This will wrap the default prompts that are internal to llama-index
    query_wrapper_prompt = SimpleInputPrompt("<|USER|>{query_str}<|ASSISTANT|>")


    llm = HuggingFaceLLM(
        context_window=4096,
        max_new_tokens=256,
        generate_kwargs={"temperature": 0.7, "do_sample": False},
        system_prompt=system_prompt,
        query_wrapper_prompt=query_wrapper_prompt,
        tokenizer_name="StabilityAI/stablelm-tuned-alpha-3b",
        model_name="StabilityAI/stablelm-tuned-alpha-3b",
        device_map="auto",
        stopping_ids=[50278, 50279, 50277, 1, 0],
        tokenizer_kwargs={"max_length": 4096},
        # uncomment this if using CUDA to reduce memory usage
        # model_kwargs={"torch_dtype": torch.float16}
    )
    #llm=ChatOpenAI(temperature=0.7, model_name="gpt-3.5-turbo", max_tokens=num_outputs)
    #llm_predictor = LLMPredictor(llm=llm)
    service_context = ServiceContext.from_defaults(chunk_size=1024, llm=llm)

    documents = SimpleDirectoryReader(directory_path).load_data()

    index = VectorStoreIndex.from_documents(documents, service_context=service_context)
    #index = VectorStoreIndex(documents, llm_predictor=llm_predictor, prompt_helper=prompt_helper)

    index.storage_context.persist(persist_dir=storage_path)

    return index

def chatbot(input_text):
    index = load_index_from_storage(StorageContext.from_defaults(persist_dir=storage_path))
    #index = GPTVectorStoreIndex.load_from_disk('index.json')
    #query_engine = index.as_query_engine(response_synthesizer=response_synthesizer);
    query_engine = index.as_query_engine(streaming=True)

    response = query_engine.query(input_text)

    print(response.source_nodes)

    relevant_files=[]

    for node_with_score in response.source_nodes:
        print(node_with_score)
        print(node_with_score.node)
        print(node_with_score.node.metadata)
        print(node_with_score.node.metadata['file_name'])

        file = node_with_score.node.metadata['file_name']
        print( file )

        # Resolve the full file path for the downloading
        full_file_path = Path( docs_path, file ).resolve()

        # See if it's already in the array
        if full_file_path not in relevant_files:
            relevant_files.append( full_file_path ) # Add it

    print( relevant_files )

    return response.get_response(), relevant_files

iface = gr.Interface(fn=chatbot,
                     inputs=gr.components.Textbox(lines=7, label="Enter your text"),
                     outputs=[
                        gr.components.Textbox(label="Response"), 
                        gr.components.File(label="Relevant Files")
                        ],
                     title="Custom-trained AI Chatbot",
                     allow_flagging="never")

index = construct_index(docs_path)
iface.launch(share=False)
```

Regardless, the code errors out saying:

```
ValueError: No API key found for OpenAI.
Please set either the OPENAI_API_KEY environment variable or openai.api_key prior to initialization.
API keys can be found or created at https://platform.openai.com/account/api-keys
```

Am I not understanding how to set up a local model?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Turns out I had to set the embed_model to "local" on the ServiceContext.

```py
ServiceContext.from_defaults(chunk_size=1024, llm=llm, embed_model="local")
```

Also, when I was loading the vector index from disk I wasn't setting the llm predictor again which cause a secondary issue. So I decided to make the vector index a global variable. Here is my final code that works.

```py
from pathlib import Path
import gradio as gr
import sys
import logging
import os

from llama_index.llms import HuggingFaceLLM
from llama_index.prompts.prompts import SimpleInputPrompt

logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.getLogger().addHandler(logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout))


from llama_index import SimpleDirectoryReader, VectorStoreIndex, ServiceContext, load_index_from_storage, StorageContext

storage_path = "storage"

docs_path="docs"

print(storage_path)

max_input_size = 4096
num_outputs = 512
#max_chunk_overlap = 20
chunk_overlap_ratio = 0.1
chunk_size_limit = 600


system_prompt = """<|SYSTEM|># StableLM Tuned (Alpha version)
- StableLM is a helpful and harmless open-source AI language model developed by StabilityAI.
- StableLM is excited to be able to help the user, but will refuse to do anything that could be considered harmful to the user.
- StableLM is more than just an information source, StableLM is also able to write poetry, short stories, and make jokes.
- StableLM will refuse to participate in anything that could harm a human.
"""

# This will wrap the default prompts that are internal to llama-index
query_wrapper_prompt = SimpleInputPrompt("<|USER|>{query_str}<|ASSISTANT|>")


llm = HuggingFaceLLM(
    context_window=4096,
    max_new_tokens=256,
    generate_kwargs={"temperature": 0.7, "do_sample": False},
    system_prompt=system_prompt,
    query_wrapper_prompt=query_wrapper_prompt,
    tokenizer_name="StabilityAI/stablelm-tuned-alpha-3b",
    model_name="StabilityAI/stablelm-tuned-alpha-3b",
    device_map="auto",
    stopping_ids=[50278, 50279, 50277, 1, 0],
    tokenizer_kwargs={"max_length": 4096},
    # uncomment this if using CUDA to reduce memory usage
    # model_kwargs={"torch_dtype": torch.float16}
)

service_context = ServiceContext.from_defaults(chunk_size=1024, llm=llm, embed_model="local")

documents = SimpleDirectoryReader(docs_path).load_data()

index = VectorStoreIndex.from_documents(documents, service_context=service_context)


def chatbot(input_text):
    query_engine = index.as_query_engine()

    response = query_engine.query(input_text)

    print(response.source_nodes)

    relevant_files=[]

    for node_with_score in response.source_nodes:
        print(node_with_score)
        print(node_with_score.node)
        print(node_with_score.node.metadata)
        print(node_with_score.node.metadata['file_name'])

        file = node_with_score.node.metadata['file_name']
        print( file )

        # Resolve the full file path for the downloading
        full_file_path = Path( docs_path, file ).resolve()

        # See if it's already in the array
        if full_file_path not in relevant_files:
            relevant_files.append( full_file_path ) # Add it

    print( relevant_files )

    return response.response, relevant_files

iface = gr.Interface(fn=chatbot,
                     inputs=gr.components.Textbox(lines=7, label="Enter your text"),
                     outputs=[
                        gr.components.Textbox(label="Response"), 
                        gr.components.File(label="Relevant Files")
                        ],
                     title="Custom-trained AI Chatbot",
                     allow_flagging="never")

iface.launch(share=False)
```

Answer (score -1):

The error is here:

```
        tokenizer_name="StabilityAI/stablelm-tuned-alpha-3b",
        model_name="StabilityAI/stablelm-tuned-alpha-3b",
```

the HF LLM you're trying to use is hosted on the HuggingFace Model Hub, which requires an API key for access-- tokenizer_name + model_name parameters are  "StabilityAI/stablelm-tuned-alpha-3b", which is a model hosted on the  Hub. you need to download the model files and then provide the path to the local model files as the model_name parameter.

You can download a model from the HuggingFace Model Hub using the transformers-cli command-line tool:

```
transformers-cli download --model StabilityAI/stablelm-tuned-alpha-3b
```

and add that to the code like this:

```
llm = HuggingFaceLLM(
    # blah blah blah
    model_name="FILE_LOCATION/StabilityAI/stablelm-tuned-alpha-3b",
    # blah blah blah
)
```

Comment: I wanted to accept your answer BUT it was the same results as downloading the model myself. They both stored it in the same cache directory. Even linking explicitly caused the same issue.

Comment: I don't see merit in this answer. Why will the code ask for OpenAI key even if it has to download the model from HF?

Comment: you can download it or you can use the key-- the original code tried to access HF's hub, which requires an API key, but if you download it you don't have to use the key. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67595500/how-to-download-model-from-huggingface , https://huggingface.co/docs/huggingface_hub/v0.5.1/en/package_reference/hf_api , https://huggingface.co/docs/huggingface_hub/v0.7.0.rc0/en/how-to-inference